# Custom user no password in db

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

When I try logging in with my custom user model I have been getting 'Please enter a correct email and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.'. When I check the database I see the superuser has a password but my test user does not.

Things I've tried:

- Checking database for users (They're present but no password)
- Dropping database and running makemigrations
- Superuser can login on both admin and regular login form just fine

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, 
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin,
)

# Create your models here.


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, company, phone, is_active=True, is_admin=False, is_staff=False, is_dealer=False, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a last name")
        if not company:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a company")
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a phone number")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.first_name = first_name
        user_obj.last_name = last_name
        user_obj.company = company
        user_obj.phone = phone
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.dealer = is_dealer
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, company, phone, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            company,
            phone,
            password=password,
            is_admin=True,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_company_staff_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, company, phone, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            company,
            phone,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user
    
    def create_dealer_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, company, phone, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            company,
            phone,
            password=password,
            is_dealer=True
        )
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dealer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # USERNAME_FIELD and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'phone']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_dealer(self):
        return self.dealer  

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_online(self):
        return self.online
```

**accounts/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Register your models here.

User = get_user_model()

admin.site.register(User)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

**main/templates/registration/login.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card my-4">
    {% load static %}
    <img class="img-fluid pb-4" src="{% static 'img/logos/logo-black.png' %}">

    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
      please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|crispy }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**myproject/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include('main.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I don't know what else to try. All I need is to be able to sign in with email rather than a username and have two types of users. (staff and dealer)

EDIT: I just checked my database and it appears there is not a password for my test user.

Comment: Is `is_active` true for the user?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it is. I just updated my question as I believe it's not entering passwords for my test users.

Comment: How are you creating the test user?

Comment: @IainShelvington Through the admin

Answer (score 0):

You should register your User model with the `UserAdmin` from the auth package. It *should* just plug into your model and will give you the custom forms that will create your users correctly

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

User = get_user_model()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: It gives me `<class 'django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'is_active', which does not refer to a Field.` and a bunch of similar errors

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign **password=password** like this. Instead try *user.set_password(password)*

Comment: When I swap out 'password=password' with user.set_password(password) I get `Using variable 'user' before assignment`